# Know when pan gesture passes the bounds of the view

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to figure out when a user finger passes the bounds of a scroll view. This is how my view controller looks like.

[image]

Now when the user finger passes the bounds of the scroll view I would like the scroll view to stop scrolling. But as of now the scroll view will continue to scroll. How would I be able to detect when a user finger has pass the bounds of the view, in which the gesture was added to?

Comment: You know where the finger is, and you know where the view is. So how can you _not_ know when the finger is outside the view?

Comment: If you're using a scrollview why don't you just check the contentOffset?

Comment: I really don't know where the finger is or when the finger goes outside the view. That is what I need help with. But if you can provide a link explaining it, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: try youview.bounds.contains(CGPoint)